# How to create select list with array names in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I mean to create select list:

```
<select name="type[]"></select>
<select name="type[]"></select>
```

That on server I could check variable like as:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('type[]', 'Type', 'integer');
```

N

Now I have two different select list:

```
<select ng-model="formData.beginDateDay[1]" class="form-control" required>
       <option ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:31">{{y}}</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="formData.beginDateDay[2]" class="form-control" required>
       <option ng-repeat="y in [] | range:0:31">{{y}}</option>
</select>
```

And on server I want to get `$_POST['beginDateDay']`

Comment: are you submitting by ajax? If so can use any name you want as you will be submitting the `ng-model` which can be set up using arrays. If not add an index to the name. WHat specific problems are you running into?

Comment: Yes, by AJAX, I tried `ng-model="type[1]"` and `ng-model="type[2]"`

Comment: I can do different `ng-model` for each select, but it is not cose

Comment: What does that mean? Please be as concise as possible in your question and replies. Still not clear what your specific problem is. Sending `formData` object from controller scope should give you exactly what you asked for in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure myself, but here is a seemingly reliable source: http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/08/angularjs-dropdown-list.html. I hope this is what you are looking for.